# python pandas weird indexing for multiple rows but not one

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have been playing around with pandas indexing and stumbled upon something pretty odd. I am trying to assign multiple rows of one dataframe to another dataframe. Assigning one row works, but assigning multiple rows does not. Below is some reproducible data. I generate my two dataframes.

```
centers=pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=list(string.ascii_uppercase[:3]), columns=['x','y'])
data=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,2), index=range(50), columns=['x','y'])
```

Centers is an empty dataframe and I want to make the first three rows of 'centers' equal to the first three rows of 'data'.

```
centers 
    x   y
A NaN NaN
B NaN NaN
C NaN NaN

data.head()
          x         y
0  1.195444  0.666973
1 -0.933807 -0.382923
2  0.582849  0.533059
3 -0.411232 -1.142588
4  0.144402 -0.991504
```

Originally, I thought it was an indexing issue as centers has letters and data has numbers. However I no longer think this is the case, because indexing one row at a time gives me the desired result. Here is zero index and here is one index both with desired results.

```
centers.iloc[0,:]=data.ix[0,['x','y']]
centers 
          x         y
A  1.195444  0.666973
B       NaN       NaN
C       NaN       NaN

centers.iloc[1,:]=data.ix[1,['x','y']]
centers
          x         y
A  1.195444  0.666973
B -0.933807 -0.382923
C       NaN       NaN
```

However doing this with multiple rows does not.

```
centers.iloc[0:3,:]=data.ix[0:2,['x','y']]
centers
    x   y
A NaN NaN
B NaN NaN
C NaN NaN
```

Each dataframe individually is exactly what I think it is.

```
centers.iloc[0:3,:]
    x   y
A NaN NaN
B NaN NaN
C NaN NaN

data.ix[0:2,['x','y']]
          x         y
0  1.195444  0.666973
1 -0.933807 -0.382923
2  0.582849  0.533059
```

Why might this be the case and how do I fix it? (I know I can solve this exact issue by setting centers equal to my data index, but I want an answer with indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the indices don't match hence no assignment occurs if you call `.values` to return a `np.array` then it works:

```
In [76]:
print(centers.iloc[0:3,:])
print(data.ix[0:2,['x','y']])

    x   y
A NaN NaN
B NaN NaN
C NaN NaN
          x         y
0 -1.081909 -0.672130
1 -0.144562  0.863694
2  0.214779  1.193998

In [77]:    
centers.iloc[0:3,:] = data.ix[0:2,['x','y']].values
centers

Out[77]:
          x         y
A -1.081909 -0.672130
B -0.144562  0.863694
C  0.214779  1.193998
```

So what you're observing is not a bug, it is by design

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see that the indices do not match, but when I just do the first index, centers is index A and data is index 0 and it works. If I replace 1 with 0 it works too. So only when I do multiple rows does it break, thus I do not think it is in index not matching issue

Comment: Please edit your question demonstrating how you think that aligning on the index doesn't work and is not relevant

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my response, I have added the changing 1 index in my question

Comment: When you select a single row and assign to a single row it's a series so there is no alignment on the index needed, when you select multiple rows you return a df and assign to a df, alignment is performed on the index and columns hence the error